# Jira issue solved per week, irrespective of creation date

Tags: jira

How can I create a weekly graph in Jira, that shows me how many issues per solved per week, irrespective when they were created.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what version of JIRA are you using (hosted or OnDemand)?  Are you using sprints / agile boards / Greenhopper?  If you have those, then you should be able to leverage the burndown chart (and many other reports) in the Report tab of an agile board.

for custom details, you can use the issues search feature.  and filter by resolution date

```
resolutiondate >= startOfWeek()
```